# insert new input file when user click symbol

Tags: javascript, html

How i can allow user to add for example his need of books with number, this needs have no limited no, so if he click on add another  the web page will open a new input field .
At the end he will click submit button .

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{?>
<td><input type="submit" value="Add another"/></td>

<?php } ?


?>
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="need"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Add another"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will want to do this client-side, with Javascript.

It would be fairly trivial to implement some JS to add a new `<input>` element to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic Javascript, I created a small Demo Example to help you understand. If you have any questions let me know.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VdW3P/1/

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Demo</legend>
<form method="POST">
<div id="dynamicInput">
          Entry 1<br /><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></br>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing your using Php and MySql, Have a look at this link it provides beginner level tutorial on how to do this: http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~hankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html